# How can I display more than 5 nodes on a taxonomy view for one vocabulary?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a web site where videos are posted and each video is a part of a series. The series name is a taxonomy term in a vocabulary. Many of the series have more than 5 parts and I cannot figure out how to have the taxonomy view page for these to either add a "more" link, use a pager, or display all nodes referenced by the particular taxonomy term within that vocabulary.

You can see an example of this at http://www.clctc.org/discussion-series/desperation

There are 6 nodes tagged with the "Desperation" term from the "Discussion Series" vocabulary. The page only shows 5 and there is no pager or more link.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

There is two things you should check.

- Re-check if the taxonomy(tags) are referenced correctly in each content.
- Secondly check the pager section in views, for pages, offset and more link settings.

[image]